# How to create plots for filtered data in rmarkdown document without using Shiny?

Tags: r, r-markdown

The [Data Table (DT) library](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) can be used to create tables in a rmarkdown document without using Shiny package. You can filter the table columns to display selected data. Is there any such thing for plots? I could use Shiny but don't want to turn my document to a Shiny doc.
Following is the code and resulting plot I am using. I want to be able to filter the plot by 'sp.interval', 'Vehicle.type' and 'period':

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(data = df15 %>% filter(sacc>0)) +
      geom_density(aes(x = sacc, group = sp.interval, color=sp.interval)) +
      facet_wrap(period~Vehicle.type) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: it's not on CRAN, but [taucharts](github.com/hrbrmstr/taucharts) makes this possible. there are many more [htmlwidgets](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/) that could also help this.

Comment: @hrbrmstr taucharts are great BUT there is no option to create histogram/density plots.